# Pass python string/unicode object to sqlite

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite, scrapy

I've fallen deep into unicode hell somewhere between Python and sqlite. I'm trying to do something I thought was simple:

1) Scrape a website with scrapy ==> 2) Extract main text content with lxml ==> 3) Pass text into an SQLite database.

The first two steps are simple, using this code:

```
class OpEdSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "opeds"
  allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
  start_urls = ["http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html"]

  def parse(self, response):
    data = response.body
    into_lxml = html.fromstring(data)
    raw_content = unicode(into_lxml.text_content())
    print raw_content
```

The first part uses Python's scrapy library to scrape the site; the parse function extracts fairly clean text through lxml's `text_content()` attribute (I'm not interested in precise html/xml structure; what this function gives me is text that's clean enough to be used for analysis down the road). Printing `raw_content` with or without `unicode()` shows the content I want, formatted the way I want it. `type(raw_content)` is, as expected, `lxml.etree._*` or `unicode`, respectively.

Things fall apart when I try to add `raw_content` to an SQLite database, replacing the `print` function with this function:

```
class OpEdSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "opeds"
  allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
  start_urls = ["http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html"]

  def parse(self, response):
    data = response.body
    into_lxml = html.fromstring(data)
    raw_content = unicode(into_lxml.text_content(),)
    add_to_db(raw_content)

def add_to_db(item):
  conn = sqlite3.connect('testproject_tracker.db')
  c = conn.cursor()

  c.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists tracker
            (web_content TEXT)''')

  c.execute("INSERT INTO tracker VALUES (?)", (item,))

  conn.commit()

  for row in c.execute('SELECT * from tracker'):
    print row

  conn.close()
```

What used to be nicely cleaned-up output from `raw_content` now looks terrible (here's a small sample):

> \n\'Example title\'\n\n\nSpiders are expected to return their scraped data inside\nItem objects.

And here's where I'm lost. `raw_content` is a unicode text object; the SQLite column (web_content) is supposed to accept unicode. Yet somewhere, `raw_content` gets encoded/decoded into the mess above.

I've researched this to a point where I think I understand what the problem, but not the solution is (but please correct me if I'm wrong). `raw_content` is passed as a tuple to sqlite*, which likely breaks the unstructured text in the raw_content variable into separate elements of a tuple (lines maybe?), which then show up separated by `\n` and other strings in the database. How can I avoid that? Is it possible to pass `raw_content` as-is into SQLite; i.e., to pass into the database precisely what printing `raw_content` shows before it's passed into the database?

Apologies for the lengthy question. I'm trying to balance conciseness with enough detail to not make others replicate failed solutions I've tried.

[* if I don't pass `raw_content` as a tuple (if I remove the trailing `,`), I get the following error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 25741 supplied.

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `print row[0]`

I think its actually fine ... row is a list so you are seeing the repr of the string rather than the string itself

```
>>> x = ["hello\nworld"] #essentially equivelent to your row variable
>>> print x
['hello\nworld'] #this is likely simillar to what you are seeing
>>> print x[0] #when you want to see this
hello
world
```

I guess... (e.g. I dont think its encoding/decoding anything, its just saving the raw bytes ... but select statements return a list... printing a list prints the repr of items in the list, instead of printing the actual list)

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks! The text was stored inside the database correctly the whole time, but the printout in python made me think something was wrong. This solution lets me both store _and_ print it correctly.